# Execute a bpmn from Camunda Modeler

Tags: bpmn, camunda, bpmn.io

Has anyone found how to execute a diagram modeled in camunda's new modeler? With the old eclipse plug-in I could build the model with maven and put the war file on the apache server (https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/bpmn20/deploy/). Is there a way to export as war from the new modeler?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The scope of the Camunda Modeler is the creation and annotation of BPMN2, CMMN and DMN models. In the next step you insert your finished model in your IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ, ...) and use maven to build the WAR file.

These steps are also explained in the getting started guide:
https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/bpmn20/